# maximum of a probability function

Tags: probability

I am reading Andrew Ng's [notes on Factor Analysis](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes9.pdf). On page 7, the author intends to maximize [equation 4:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHefX.png).

Based on my interpretation of the rest of the notes, the author's strategy is to first take derivative with respect to Λ and find the optimal Λ that maximizes equation 4, and then do the same things for µ and Ψ. 
If the author optimized the equation with regards to Λ, µ, and Ψ simultaneously, I can see the resulting parameters can be used to optimize the equation by definition. But why is it the combination of Λ, µ, and Ψ, each found by optimizing the equation with respect to ONE variable, guaranteed to optimize the equation?

Here's a simplified analogy: Here is the [picture of a concave Gaussian distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYUIh.png). Let's say we're at the orange point. There's no way that by finding the x' that optimizes the function with respect to x only, and the y' that optimizes the function with respect to y only, you can use x' and y' to optimize the function, because the optimal x and y cannot be reached from the point if you're changing one variable at a time.

Thanks.

Comment: That's the point of the EM algorithm--which Ng is constructing here for a particular model--to repeatedly optimise along different directions (in the interest of computational tractability). More generally such methods are called coordinate descent, or alternating minimisation, and convergence of these for 'nice' convex functions is fairly well understood - consult any conv. optimisation text. In particular, EM is known to converge to a local optimum - the wiki page on it is a decent start if you want more intuition, and Ng would almost surely have some treatment of it in a previous chapter.

Comment: Well, in his notes on EM, Ng does say EM is a coordinate descent algorithm (see page 6 in following link) https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes8.pdf. But the coordinates in this case are Q, and theta, and I believe that the theta in my original question is an umbrella term for all three parameters Λ, µ, and Ψ. For the M step in EM algorithm, am I not supposed to globally maximize the function with respect to theta analytically?

Comment: Oh, I think I've misunderstood your question - your issue is not with the EM alg, but with the particulars of the M-step in this case. I'll probably have to read the thing to figure it out, but generically note that the standard way to optimise a function $J(\theta)$ is to demand that $\nabla J = 0,$ which is equivalent to saying that $\partial_{\theta_i} J = 0$ for each $i$ simultaneously. Could it be that Ng notationally separates such a $\theta$ into $\Lambda, \mu, \Psi,$ and this is leading to confusion?

Comment: Yes I believe Ng separates θ into Λ,μ,Ψ in this problem. That's why I don't understand how he can find the maximum by individually solving for the zero gradients for each of those terms separately. MAYBE we're meant to use coordinate ascent WITHIN the M step using coordinates Λ,μ,Ψ?

Comment: No, that's the thing, he's not doing them separately - he's doing them simultaneously. Basically, $\nabla_{\Lambda, \mu, \Psi} J = 0$ would give you three equations in $(\Lambda, \mu, \Phi)$ that need to be simultaneously satisfied. In the text, he writes out the equation due to $\nabla_{\Lambda},$ and solves for $\Lambda$ in terms of $(\mu, \Psi).$ What he doesn't do (but intends for the reader to do, I guess) is to plug this expression for $\Lambda$ into the $\nabla_\mu$ and $\nabla_\Psi$ equations to 'eliminate the variable', and then solve those out further.

Comment: Yeah, so, the end of page 7 he's computed $\nabla_{\Lambda}$ and has equated it to $0$. If you explicitly write this out, you get $\Psi^{-1} \left(\sum_i \mathbb{E}[\textrm{stuff involving $\Lambda, \mu$}] \right) = 0.$ But $\Psi \succ 0,$ so this implies that the stuff multiplying it is $0$, which then allows you to solve for $\Lambda$ in terms of $\mu.$ One would simultaneously consider the equations due to $\nabla_{\mu, \Psi},$ and perhaps eliminate $\Lambda$ from them by this relation.

Comment: Mm. I think i got the main gist. I'll ponder more about it tomorrow when my brain is working again. Thanks!